# JavaFX How do I scale the coordinates of a Path without altering the line width?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scale, transformation

I am currently working on a step line chart with a zoom and panning functionality. Since the amount of data I need to process is pretty large, i can not afford to recreate the whole path of the step line, every time layoutPlotChildren() is called. So my idea was to create the path element once and just transform it on zoom an pan events.

So far everything worked out as planned, but i am having a big problem when I'm trying to scale the path. Since the Path class is inherited from Shape, scaling on the Graph not only transforms the coordinates of the path, but also alters its thickness.

I created a minimal working example to present the problem:

```
public class Sandbox extends Application
{

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(0, 0));
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(100, 0));
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(100, 100));
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(200, 100));

        path.setScaleY(3);

        Pane pane = new StackPane(path);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the coordinates are scaled as intended, but all horizontal lines are three times as thick as before. I completely understand, why this is happening, but I can't think of any possibilities to prevent the thickening of the lines. Do you have any suggestions on how I could solve this problem while still assuring acceptable performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this is not a problem of the `Shape` class, but a problem of what scaling actually does: A in `Node` scaled with a factor `x` every distance is rendered `x` times as long as in the unscaled `Node`. This includes the thickness of any lines.

You could however modify the coordinates of your path elements by multiplying the coordinates with the scale factor however:

```
// class for holing a pair of (x, y) properties with method for modifying the values based on scale
public static class PointScaler {

    private final DoubleProperty xProperty;
    private final DoubleProperty yProperty;
    private final double x0;
    private final double y0;

    public PointScaler(DoubleProperty xProperty, DoubleProperty yProperty) {
        this.xProperty = xProperty;
        this.yProperty = yProperty;

        // save untransformed values
        this.x0 = xProperty.get();
        this.y0 = yProperty.get();
    }

    public void setScale(double factor) {
        xProperty.set(factor * x0);
        yProperty.set(factor * y0);
    }

}

private double scaleFactor = 1;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Path path = new Path();
    MoveTo m0 = new MoveTo(0, 0);
    LineTo l0 = new LineTo(100, 0);
    LineTo l1 = new LineTo(100, 100);
    LineTo l2 = new LineTo(200, 100);
    path.getElements().addAll(m0, l0, l1, l2);

    // create list with scaler for each (x,y) pair in the path elements
    List<PointScaler> scalers = new ArrayList<>();
    scalers.add(new PointScaler(m0.xProperty(), m0.yProperty()));
    scalers.add(new PointScaler(l0.xProperty(), l0.yProperty()));
    scalers.add(new PointScaler(l1.xProperty(), l1.yProperty()));
    scalers.add(new PointScaler(l2.xProperty(), l2.yProperty()));

    Pane pane = new StackPane(path);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);

    // change scale on click of mouse buttons
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        if (evt.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            scaleFactor *= 1.2;
        } else if (evt.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            scaleFactor /= 1.2;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        // apply scale to path points
        for (PointScaler scaler : scalers) {
            scaler.setScale(scaleFactor);
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note that the `setScale` method keeps x and y scale the same but it shouldn't be too hard modify the method to work for different transforms. Note that some `PathElement`s like `CubicCurveTo` and `QuadCurveTo` require more than a single `PointScaler` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [fabians great response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48506035/4240433), I created my own solution, which is a simplified version for step lines (my initial problem), but not nearly as flexible as the aforementioned response. I will post my answer here for completeness, but I still think fabians answers has to be the accepted one.

```
public class Sandbox extends Application
{

    private DoubleProperty scaleX = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1d);
    private DoubleProperty scaleY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1d);

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(0, 0));

        path.getElements().add(createLineTo(100, 0));
        path.getElements().add(createLineTo(100, 100));
        path.getElements().add(createLineTo(200, 100));

        scaleY.setValue(3);

        Pane pane = new StackPane(path);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private LineTo createLineTo(double x, double y)
    {
        LineTo lineTo = new LineTo();
        lineTo.xProperty().bind(scaleX.multiply(x));
        lineTo.yProperty().bind(scaleY.multiply(y));
        return lineTo;
    }
}
```

This mainly prevents the foreach loop and the need to create a separate class, but as mentioned before, this is not as versatile as fabians answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to just apply the inverse scale to the strokeWidthProperty of each Shape. This can be easily done via binding.
So if your Path is scaled by s = 3 for example you have to bind the strokeWidthProperty to w*1/3 where w is the nominal stroke width.

Comment: Wouldn't this limit the scale to one direction? Or can i apply the stroke width depending on the direction of a line?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What has the direction of the line to do with its scale?

Comment: So assuming I would use your method to adjust the stroke width. Then I would scale horizontally by a factor of 10 and vertically by a factor of 5. How would I adjust the stroke width?